# GC overhead limit exceeded Android Studio

Tags: android, out-of-memory, jack, heap-size

When I run my project, The next error shows up.

```
        Error:Execution failed for task ':MyApp:compileDebugJavaWithJack'. > java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
```

But I am using the code below in my build.gradle file.

```
            dexOptions {
            incremental true
                javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
            }
```

What can I do to avoid this failure?. Could anyone please help me out?